# R identifying and aggregating balances with no history

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, aggregation

I have a group of accounts with balances over 4 months.  I want to a sum the balances that have just appeared that particular month.  This is what I have gotten so far.

One account originated (new) each month.

```
Accounts <- c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C')
Dates <- as.Date(c('2016-01-31', '2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31'))
Balances <- c(100,NA,NA,90,50,NA,80,40,120)
Origination <- data.frame(Dates,Accounts,Balances)

library(reshape2)
Origination <- dcast(Origination,Dates ~ Accounts, value.var = "Balances")
Origination$Originated <- apply(Origination[2:4],1,function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x))==nrow(Origination),NA,tail(na.omit(x),1)))
Origination <- melt(Origination, id = c("Dates"))
Origination <-dcast(Origination, variable ~ Dates, value.var = "value")

    variable 2016-01-31 2016-02-29 2016-03-31
1          A        100         90         80
2          B         NA         50         40
3          C         NA         NA        120
4 Originated        100         50        120
```

This creates an origination table with a row called Originated.  First month we only have the 100, second month we have the amortized A to 90 but also a new account 50 and last month we have both the amortized A and B with new C at 120.  The Originated Column captures it exactly as I want.

But if I introduce another account D with in month 2 it picks just that amount (10) and not the sum of the two that is being originated. ie 50 (B) plus the 10(C).

```
Accounts <- c('A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D')
Dates <- as.Date(c('2016-01-31', '2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31'))
Balances <- c(100,NA,NA,NA,90,50,10,NA,80,40,5,120)
Origination <- data.frame(Dates,Accounts,Balances)

library(reshape2)
Origination <- dcast(Origination,Dates ~ Accounts, value.var = "Balances")
Origination$Originated <- apply(Origination[2:4],1,function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x))==nrow(Origination),NA,tail(na.omit(x),1)))
Origination <- melt(Origination, id = c("Dates"))
Origination <-dcast(Origination, variable ~ Dates, value.var = "value")

    variable 2016-01-31 2016-02-28 2016-03-31
1          A        100         90         80
2          B         NA         50         40
3          C         NA         10          5
4          D         NA         NA        120
5 Originated        100         10          5
```

So the ask is, how do I sum the newly added accounts from A through D across dates.  Perhaps I am over thinking it.  The result I would like is this:

```
    variable 2016-01-31 2016-02-28 2016-03-31
1          A        100         90         80
2          B         NA         50         40
3          C         NA         10          5
4          D         NA         NA        120
5 Originated        100         60        120
```

Help is much appreciated.
Aksel

Comment: for each individual column A:D you can solve by only taking values where the lagged value is NA. e.g. for A. `Origination$Originated_A <- ifelse(is.na(dplyr::lag(Origination$A)), Origination$A, 0)`. You just need to do that within the apply for all and sum

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I seem to be having issue with the apply function.  I can not get it to work on the 4 columns following the date column.  The example is just a sample. I will need to do the calculations on around 1000 accounts. thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to get the output I want.  Here is the answer for those whom are interested.

```
sel <- rbind(FALSE, !is.na(head(Origination[-1], -1)))
#sel
#         A     B     C     D
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

rowSums(replace(Origination[-1], sel, 0), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 100  60 120
```